# How do I solve this recurrence equation using the characteristics method?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

> Solve the following recurrence equation using the characteristics equation where n is a power of 2:
>
> $$T(n) = 7T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) +  18\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2, T(1) = 0, n>1$$

I thought of converting it into a linear recurrence, which I almost managed to do:

$$2^k=n$$
$$T(2^k)=7T(2^{k-1})+18(2^{k-1})^2$$
$$T(m) = T(2^k)$$
$$T(m) = 7T(m-1) + 18(2^{m-1})^2$$

But this is definitely wrong because of the last term. Any workaround?

Comment: Let $\,n=2^k\,$ and define $\,a_k = T(2^k)\,$ then $\,a_k = 7\, a_{k-1}+ 18 \cdot 2^{2k-2}\,$. Divide by $2^{2k-2}$ and define $b_k = \dfrac{a_k}{2^{2k}}$ then $\dots$

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Consider also adding it as an answer.

Comment: Feel free to fill in the blanks and post a self answer, I'll +1 it.

Comment: I would feel guilty getting extra rep on someone's work. At least copy your comment into an answer and I will add the rest of the working :)

Comment: Expanded into an answer, though there still are a few minor blanks left to fill in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

- let $n=2^k$ and define $a_k=T(2^k)$ then the recurrence becomes

$$T\left(2^k\right) = 7\, T\left(2^{k-1}\right) + 18 \cdot \left(2^{k-1}\right)^2\;\;\iff\;\; a_k = 7\,a_{k-1} + 18\cdot 2^{2k-2} \tag{1}$$

- divide $(1)$ by $2^{2k-2}=2^{2(k-1)}$ and define $b_k=\dfrac{a_k}{2^{2k}}$ then

$$
{\color{blue}{4}} \, \frac{a_k}{2^{2k-2} \cdot \color{blue}{4}} = 7\,\frac{a_{k-1}}{2^{2(k-1)}} + 18 \;\;\iff\;\; 4\,b_k = 7 b_{k-1} + 18 \tag{2}
$$

Relation $(2)$ is a linear recurrence with constant coefficients, which can be solved with the usual methods. Or directly, writing it as $4\left(b_k + 6\right) = 7\left(b_{k-1}+6\right)$ shows that $c_k = b_k + 6$ is a geometric progression, so
$\,c_k = c_0 \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^k\,$, $\,b_k=c_k - 6\,$, $\,a_k = 2^{2k}b_k\,$, $T(n)=a_{\log_2 n}\,$.